# Display language for MapControl in UWP

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml, uwp-maps

I need to change language of labels on the Map, like continents, countries, cities, streets etc.

I've tried to use **Language** property but it does not matter, always labels are on English

```
xmlns:maps="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps"

<Grid>
    <maps:MapControl />
</Grid>
```

Is it supported?

Comment: I think if your app supports more languages the MapControl could maybe adapt the currently used language.

Comment: It's strange, on Windows 10 Mobile device this UWP app is localized, but on Desktop - not, although region/localization settings are same - uk-ua

Comment: What do you mean by that? By supporting more languages in your app I meant having string resources in the app so it is in the language as Windows is - at least for the languages you need (see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/globalizing/globalizing-portal) for more info about UWP localization).

Comment: My comment was not answer to your suggestion about app localization. I've just noticed that map can be localized in UWP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UWP map control will always use the Display language setting of the OS for map labels. There is currently no way to override this on a per map control instance basis.
In addition, not every label is localized in every language. Even if the OS display language is set to French, for example, you may still see labels in English or other languages depending on what part of the world you're looking at and which language you have set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It sounds like true, but in my home PC I have Ukrainian display language and map is not localized, although the same app on a phone is localized, and yes, the phone also has Ukrainian display language. So, in general it's true but with some nuances :-)

Comment: I have answer, MapControl uses default keyboard language instead of display language to choose which one use for labels